# Toggling in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Is it possible to Hide/Show detail section when click on the group header in `Crystal Reports 2008`? When user click on the group header it expands/collapse the detail section.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really expand or collapse when you click on a group.  It opens a new tab narrowing the information of the group.  They refer to this as drilldown.

Crystal Reports has a simple drilldown where you can hide the sections (groups and/or details).  When you click on the group it will narrow that specific line and reveal the hidden section.

Another useful feature is suppression; where you can apply a formula to control what groups and detail lines to display.  When true suppress the line, when false release.  This is found in the Section Expert.  A useful function with this is "drilldowngrouplevel".  It monitors the depth levels of the drilldown which can signal when to suppress and not to suppress sections.  This in combination with the data from the group and additional sections, you can make your report dynamic.

I hope this helps.